# ChoiceAdmin inline not displaying (Django official tutorial part 7)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm doing the Django official tutorial and after editing the admin.py file to add and edit choices for poll questions my code is not working as expected. The choice-related elements do not appear below the question name entry. 
No error messages were displayed.

Tried restarting the test server, clearing the DB (sqlite3) and deleting site data in the browser.

Contents of admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Choice
from .models import Question


class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Choice model code:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

My "Add Question" page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAg1Y.jpg

Expected result: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects

Comment: What do you mean by 'my code is not working as expected'? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: My bad, clarified the first part and added some more code

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, it looks like Django isn't using your `QuestionAdmin` class at all - the *Date information* from `fieldsets` isn't displaying either. Double check that you have saved your changes to `admin.py` and that `admin.py` is in the correct folder (in `polls/admin.py` next to `models.py`). Then restart `runserver` again.

Comment: All saved and in the proper directory, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Boy that is odd - I'm not sure what the issue may be, but I think that I can confirm that your code *should* work. I added the code below to a Django app, and the result is exactly what you would expect - the question field(s), and then three choice fields: [image: the question field(s), and then three choice fields].

```
# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# admin.py    
from .models import Question, Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date',)
    list_filter = ['pub_date']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

I think the best way for you to figure this out might be to compare your own code to this repository, and see where you have any differences: https://github.com/consideratecode/django-tutorial-step-by-step/tree/2.0/7.2.2.